# How to use javascript for calling terminal or windows command in Client Side?

Tags: javascript

I want to use javascript for send command to command line for Client side , How to take it ? or it can possible?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in the arbitrary sense, no this will not be possible. Every browser and OS does its best to keep unauthorized code (like javascript in some random webpage) from accessing non-browser files and settings. Most modern browsers execute javascript (or the whole browser) in a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) that isolates it from the rest of the system.

It is conceivable that you can architect a system where software pre-deployed on the client system can take system scope actions based on input from specific web applications, but that will require custom development and extensive knowledge of the technicals involved. This is the approach ActiveX, Flash, and a number of other runtimes implement.

Some things to consider:

- Practical javascript security issues:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security
- [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)